# mongoose watch in socket

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, websocket, socket.io

I am not sure what is wrong, was working before. I am trying to receive data when there is a new document in the collection. I can see the connection is established in the frontend, but when I insert a document, it is not returning anything back.

node app.js

```
// create socket
  var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server, path: "/feed"});
  require('./sockets/feed')(wss)
```

node socket.

```
const { Comments, Following } = require('../db/models');
const { ObjectID } = require('mongodb');

module.exports = function(wss) {
    wss.once("connection", function(socket){
        socket.onmessage = async(event) =>{
            //const id = event.data; I can see frontend also passed the data

            var filter = [{
                $match: { operationType: 'insert' }
            }];
            
            var options = { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' };
            Comments.watch(filter, options)
            .on('change', data => { //NOTHING HERE?
                socket.send('feed', data);    
            })
            .on('error', err => {
              console.log(new Date() + ' error: ' + err)
            })
        };
    })

    wss.onclose = () => {
        console.log("closed");
    };
};
```

frontend

```
feeds(): Observable<any> {
    if(!this.websocket) {
      this.websocket = new WebSocket(this.feed$);

      const uId = this.auth.getUserId()
      this.websocket.onopen = () => {
        console.log("Socket connected " + this.feed$);
        this.websocket.send(uId); // was able to see it send
      }
    }
  
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      this.websocket.onmessage = (evt) => {
        observer.next(evt);
      };
    })
  }
```

Comment: Using the watch feature requires a replicaset / sharded cluster and a mongo version > 3.6. Can you tell us what your mongo setup is?

Comment: @caffeinated.tech I wasn't aware, ive recently started seeing `change stream supported only replica set` error in console. I think this points me to a direction. Thank you!